not able to connect to ytsaurus cluster using ytsaurus-ui on minikube
I am trying to connect to ytsaurus cluster but get the following errors:
Minisaurus couldn't be reached
choose cluster
It seems it has issues connecting to the cluster:
GET http://localhost:30738/api/cluster-info/minisaurus

{
    "tokenError": {
        "message": "Failed to get XSRF token :AxiosError: Request failed with status code 410",
        "code": 410,
        "inner_errors": [
            "<html>\n  <head>\n    <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=http://http-proxies-lb.default.svc.cluster.local/' />\n  </head>\n</html>\n"
        ]
    },
    "versionError": {
        "message": "Failed to get cluster version :AxiosError: Request failed with status code 410",
        "code": 410,
        "inner_errors": [
            "<html>\n  <head>\n    <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=http://http-proxies-lb.default.svc.cluster.local/' />\n  </head>\n</html>\n"
        ]
    }
}

Minikube is running on VPS under Ubuntu 22.04.2. To connect to UI I use kubectl port-forward and ssh tunnel to localhost. Localhost runs Windows 11. I have the following configuration:
minikube version: v1.32.0
minikube running pods
helm install ytsaurus oci://registry-1.docker.io/ytsaurus/ytop-chart --version 0.8.0
apiVersion: cluster.ytsaurus.tech/v1
kind: Ytsaurus
metadata:
  name: minisaurus
spec:
  coreImage: ytsaurus/ytsaurus:stable-23.1.0-relwithdebinfo

  discovery:
    instanceCount: 1

    # Make reusable loggers config with yaml anchor.
    loggers: &loggers
      - name: debug
        compression: zstd
        minLogLevel: debug
        writerType: file
        rotationPolicy: &rotationPolicy
          maxTotalSizeToKeep: 10000000
          rotationPeriodMilliseconds: 900000
        categoriesFilter:
          type: exclude
          values: ["Bus"]
      - name: info
        minLogLevel: info
        writerType: file
        rotationPolicy: *rotationPolicy
      - name: error
        minLogLevel: error
        writerType: stderr

  primaryMasters:
    instanceCount: 1
    cellTag: 1
    loggers: *loggers
    locations:
      - locationType: MasterChangelogs
        path: /yt/master-data/master-changelogs
      - locationType: MasterSnapshots
        path: /yt/master-data/master-snapshots

    volumeMounts:
      - name: master-data
        mountPath: /yt/master-data

    volumeClaimTemplates:
      - metadata:
          name: master-data
        spec:
          accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
          resources:
            requests:
              storage: 5Gi

  httpProxies:
    - serviceType: NodePort
      loggers: *loggers
      instanceCount: 1
      role: default
    - serviceType: NodePort
      loggers: *loggers
      instanceCount: 1
      role: control

  rpcProxies:
    - instanceCount: 1
      loggers: *loggers
      role: default
    - instanceCount: 1
      loggers: *loggers
      role: heavy

  dataNodes:
    - instanceCount: 3
      loggers: *loggers

      volumeMounts:
        - name: node-data
          mountPath: /yt/node-data

      locations:
        - locationType: ChunkStore
          path: /yt/node-data/chunk-store

      volumeClaimTemplates:
        - metadata:
            name: node-data
          spec:
            accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
            resources:
              requests:
                storage: 5Gi

  execNodes:
    - instanceCount: 1
      loggers: *loggers
      resources:
        limits:
          cpu: 1
          memory: 2Gi

      volumeMounts:
        - name: node-data
          mountPath: /yt/node-data

      volumes:
        - name: node-data
          emptyDir:
            sizeLimit: 5Gi

      locations:
        - locationType: ChunkCache
          path: /yt/node-data/chunk-cache
        - locationType: Slots
          path: /yt/node-data/slots

      jobProxyLoggers:
        - name: debug
          compression: zstd
          minLogLevel: debug
          writerType: file
          useTimestampSuffix: true
          rotationPolicy: &rotationPolicy
            maxTotalSizeToKeep: 10000000
            rotationPeriodMilliseconds: 900000
          categoriesFilter:
            type: exclude
            values: [ "Bus" ]
        - name: info
          minLogLevel: info
          writerType: file
          rotationPolicy: *rotationPolicy
        - name: error
          minLogLevel: error
          writerType: stderr

  schedulers:
    instanceCount: 1
    loggers: *loggers

  controllerAgents:
    instanceCount: 1
    loggers: *loggers

  ui:
    image: ytsaurus/ui:stable
    serviceType: NodePort
    instanceCount: 1

  strawberry:
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: 100Mi
    image: ytsaurus/strawberry:0.0.10

  tabletNodes:
    - instanceCount: 1

  yqlAgents:
    instanceCount: 1
    image: ytsaurus/query-tracker:0.0.6

  queryTrackers:
    instanceCount: 1
    image: ytsaurus/query-tracker:0.0.6

I think maybe this problem is connected to my user permissions but it doesn't even allow me to choose my user.
